# log-log plot running time analysis

Tags: python, algorithm, big-o

I am doing a running time analysis of an implementation of a random quick sort algorithm. The average time complexity should be O(n log n). The tests were done on integer input sizes from 2^20 to 2^30. I would like to plot the result on the log-log plot together with the O(n log n) theorical line to check for consistency.

To achieve it I am using this Python code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import linregress

# Data
input_sizes = [2**20, 2**21, 2**22, 2**23, 2**24, 2**25, 2**26, 2**27, 2**28, 2**29, 2**30]
times = [83.90, 167.00, 328.00, 673.60, 1390.50, 2863.40, 5895.60, 12253.70, 25269.50, 52770.60, 113618.54]

# Convert list to numpy arrays
input_sizes_np = np.array(input_sizes)
times_np = np.array(times)

# Create a log-log plot for the data points
plt.loglog(input_sizes_np, times_np, 'o-', label='Random Quick Sort (Integer)')

# Plot the theorical line
plt.loglog(input_sizes_np, input_sizes_np * np.log(input_sizes_np), label='Theoretical O(n log n)')

plt.xticks(input_sizes, [f'$2^{{{int(np.log2(size))}}}$' for size in input_sizes])

# Add labels
plt.xlabel('Input Size (n)')
plt.ylabel('Execution Time (ms)')

# Add a legend
plt.legend()

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

I got the representation shown in the attached image:
[image: loglog plot]

What I understood is that the algorithm is consistent with O(n log n) because the two lines are parallel and the slope is close to 0. What I don't understand is the proximity of the two lines. The algorithm one is significantly lower then the theorical one. Does this mean something? If so why and how? Is this procedure correct?

Comment: Perhaps, you forgot to attach the image

Comment: also, a general comment - everything looks linear in loglog. Goodness of fit would be a much better criterion

Comment: I am so sorry, I fixed it.

Comment: Maybe you should plot several theoretic lines, each one multiplied by a different power of 10. It would be fitting, because theory doesn't say anything about what the multiplier should be.

Answer (score 0):

You would expect the number of operations to match the number of seconds if each operation takes one second.

The lack of proximity is because computers go faster than that.

Answer (score 0):

The average time complexity is `O(n log n)`, not `n log n`. The letter `O` ("order") means "multiplied by an unknown constant". On a logarithmic plot, multiplying a function by a constant looks like moving it by some distance.